Why does this simple code crash in iOS swift?
I started having an issue in my app and I traced it to some very simple code that I've isolated and confirmed will crash my app even in the simplest case:
var dictionary: [String: String]? = [:]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dictionary?["key"] = dictionary?["key"] ?? "test"
}

it seems innocent enough, but if you run this code in a stand-alone app with no other code, you receive this error at runtime:

Thread 1: Simultaneous accesses to 0x10ce01360, but modification requires exclusive access

I've confirmed if you separate it into 2 lines, it works fine:
let currentValue = dictionary?["key"]
dictionary?["key"] = currentValue ?? "test"

But the chaining seems basic enough, I'm very surprised such simple code can cause the run-time to crash. Is this a bug, or is there a real reason the run-time can't handle this?

Simply put the two "dictionary" lines in a Swift Playground and you get the following error without even having to run the code: "overlapping accesses to 'dictionary', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable". And the issue is not specific to iOS. It appears for a macOS playground too.

See Memory Safety. The runtime technically can handle this, and this is deliberately designed to crash. Usually when you have conflicting accesses, the code won't do what you intended it to do.

I think the more interesting question is why this is not a compiler error. The compiler can successfully report an error if the dictionary is a local variable.

This has everything to do with Memory Safety. The basic principle is that it is unsafe to have reads and writes overlap with each other, so Swift stops you from doing unsafe things by crashing. It is unsafe to read from a memory location while writing to it at the same time, which is exactly what your code is doing.
dictionary?["key"] = ... is a write access to dictionary. The access starts by checking whether dictionary is nil, and if not, evaluates the expression on the right, and call the subscript setter. Only after that does the write access finish. It just so happens that "expression on the right" also contains a read access to dictionary, so Swift crashes.
In contrast, if the dictionary is not optional, doing
dictionary["key"] = dictionary["key"] ?? "value"

is fine because the write access can start after the expression on the right is evaluated.
You can also choose to always evaluate the expression on the right by copying it to a local variable, which is a different memory location, so accessing that does not overlap with the write to dictionary.
You can see more examples of overlapping accesses in the Memory Safety section of the Swift guide.
A lot of the times these overlapping accesses can be detected at compile time, but it seems like the compiler is not smart enough in this particular case. The runtime also checks for overlapping accesses, by inserting swift_beginAccess and swift_endAccess calls before and after each access. You can see how this system is implemented in Exclusivity.cpp.
In short, this is by-design - it is a safety feature that prevents you from writing to memory in undefined ways.
